# How to improve loading to for line Charts?

Tags: reporting-services

I create a this dateset and put in on a SSRS Line Chart.
X-Axis = OrderDate, Y-Axis = n_Productkey.
It always take so long to load this chart. Is it a possible to improve the speed? SSRS neet to plot every point of a day, probably this are the reason for the loading delay.

```
 SELECT 
       count([ProductKey]) as n_ProductKey
       ,convert(date, [OrderDate]) as [OrderDate]
 FROM [AdventureWorksDW2016].[dbo].[FactInternetSales]
 WHERE 1 = 1
   AND YEAR(OrderDate) = @YEAR
 GROUP BY 
   convert(date, [OrderDate]) 
 order by 2
```

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBdMS.png)

Comment: check the execution log and determine which part is taking the time, it could be the query, plotting 365 points on a chart will not take long

Comment: There were a additional dataset query, what was proceeded althouth not used. That was the reason for the delay. Good idea with the log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause.

RowCount
4398578

from an different dataset. That was queried although not used in a matrix.